# highest occurrence in list angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list and I'd like to know which numbers in this list appear most frequently, and the method would return the 3 numbers that appear most frequently.

I've tried but without success, I don't understand the logic I need to have, then I'd like to display the result in html

**ts.file**

```
public fakeJson = [
 {
   id: 1,
   boule1: 2,
   boule2: 27,
   boule3: 11,
   boule4: 50,
   boule: 39
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   boule1: 5,
   boule2: 27,
   boule3: 18,
   boule4: 44,
   boule: 31
 },
]

public highOcurrency!: number;

constructor() {
 this.getHighestOccurrence();
}

getHighestOccurrence() {
 let map = this.fakeJson.map((a) => this.fakeJson.filter((b) => a === b).length);
 return this.fakeJson[map.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, map))];
}
```

Comment: It's impossible understand the logic of the code, because has no logic (and of course don't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop over your array and check the occurence of each number, and store it into a key value :

```
const fakeJson = [
{
    id: 1,
    boule1: 2,
    boule2: 27,
    boule3: 11,
    boule4: 50,
    boule: 39,
},
{
    id: 3,
    boule1: 2,
    boule2: 27,
    boule3: 11,
    boule4: 5,
    boule: 18,
},
{
    id: 2,
    boule1: 5,
    boule2: 27,
    boule3: 18,
    boule4: 44,
    boule: 31,
}];

// transform your object into an array for easier manipulation
// easier for the answer, but deal with it inside the foreach for performances reasons
const myArray = fakeJson.map((item) => [
    item.boule1,
    item.boule2,
    item.boule3,
    item.boule4,
    item.boule,
]).flat();

// store each value found into a key value object
const counter = {};

// increase by one each value
myArray.forEach((boule) => {
    if (counter[boule]) {
        counter[boule]++;
    } else {
        counter[boule] = 1;
    }
});

// transform the counter object into a sortable array
const counterArray = [];
for (let key in counter) {
  counterArray.push({ number: key, amount: counter[key] });
}

// sort the array
counterArray.sort((a, b) => b.amount - a.amount)

console.log(counterArray);
```